# Need to format automatically numbered rows in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, string-formatting

I have a ListBox set up with automatic numbering as shown below. I want to format the number out front of each ListBoxItem so the numbers in all the rows are right aligned with each other. I figured I could use the item count to determine how many characters are in the index, using that info to set up a format in my viewmodel, and bind to it. Unfortunately I have not even figured out how to format a constant field width for my numbers. The ListBox will look a lot nicer with the contents lined up. So I need to know how to set up the format so I can bind to it.

```
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Profiles.Count}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplatedParent.(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Profile` type should have an `Index` property of some sort, which you should set.  [`AlternationCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "enables alternating containers to have a unique appearance," so I believe you're not using that correctly.  When you have that property added to your `Profile` type then you can do something for your `ItemTemplate` like:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100">
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="0 0 5 0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="{Binding Index}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This will work. I will just set the column width to something that can display 4 digit integers.

Comment: @spainchaud yeah, the column width is somewhat a separate question.  You could use padding, or you could choose to always display 4 characters  with a fixed-width font (i.e. 0001, 0002, ..., 9999), or you could calculate sizing after the binding is done and change the width based on the number of characters.  There are a number of options to choose from.